# Extend image border to body width

Tags: html, css, border

I have a document like below, which has some images with CSS borders:

```css
body {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  border: 6px solid orange;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Ut porttitor porta tellus, sit amet sodales turpis mattis vel.
<br>
<img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/routeburn_track/routeburn_flats_t.jpg" />
<br> Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Ut porttitor porta tellus, sit amet sodales turpis mattis vel.
```

[image]

I would like to extend the borders for all images in the document to the full width of the body/paragraphs, like so:

[image]

I've spent some time looking for the right CSS, but have come up empty handed. Would love some assistance!

Comment: Please add a [example].

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Newish to HTML/CSS so was not sure how to do this. I've attempted a reprex now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `<br>` to space out text. Instead use `<p>` which has default top+bottom `margin`.

For the image, you can nest the image in a containing `div`, in your case I called it `.img-wrapper` and set the border to that element. Then display the image normally.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-wrapper {
  border: 6px solid orange;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Ut porttitor porta tellus, sit amet sodales turpis mattis vel.</p>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/routeburn_track/routeburn_flats_t.jpg" /></div>
  <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Ut porttitor porta tellus, sit amet sodales turpis mattis vel.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much. Is there a way to make this the default for *all* images in the document?

Comment: @KeneDavidNwosu No problem. Yes, you can use this `.img-wrapper` div to nest all your images (given they are the same size) if you want them this way on the front-end. Just follow that same structure of the div with the image inside it on my solution. I also suggest adding `img { max-width: 100%;}` to ensure your images stay responsive with varying sizes.

Comment: Hmm I'm not 100% I understand. I am looking for a way to get all img files in the document to have this style, without having to do the nesting manually in the HTML. Perhaps this is not possible?

Comment: @KeneDavidNwosu If it wasn't the image element you could use `:before` to get this style on all elements with that `:before`. However, because it is an image you cannot do this as it is incompatible with psuedo-elements. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/bL0sm17o/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object-fit` to help here but you need to define a fixed height of your images:

```css
body {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  border: 6px solid orange;
  object-fit:contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Ut porttitor porta tellus, sit amet sodales turpis mattis vel.
<br>
<img src="https://www.quackit.com/pix/routeburn_track/routeburn_flats_t.jpg" />
<br> Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Ut porttitor porta tellus, sit amet sodales turpis mattis vel.
```